# npm request set body

Tags: node.js, request, node-modules

When using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), how do you set the request body? The `form` parameter creates a body of key value pairs: `foo=bar&baz=qux`, but how do you set the body to an arbitrary string?

Answer (score 2):

You can set request body in the options params.

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({test: 1});
};
request(options, function (err, res, body) {
  // handle err or use response and response boy
});
```

Depending upon the content you want to send, you can provide the string needed.

Comment: This is an object declaration. I'm asking how to use the request library.

Comment: Will - this is the options object you pass to request library methods.
For example: request(options, function (err, res, body) {..